# Tokenizing Strings in a File

Tags: c, string, file, tokenize

I have a file which I am tokenizing all the strings in it.

So each token gets stored in `char *token = (char *) malloc(len + 1);` The token gets released before the new one is allocated so I need a way to store the tokens for further use.

What's a good strategy to store the tokens? I have a function which prints out one single token string at a time.

My question here is not about how to tokenize or parse so please disregard the implementation of that. My question is, I have a bunch of strings that get allocated and released several times within a loop. So how would I store each allocation somewhere else for further use?

Comment: Can we see an example of this file?

Comment: can you provide some more context? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Currently your questions answer ranges from a full lexical analysis solution such a lex, or a simple string tokenizer such as `strtok`. As the others have said provide more details.

Comment: A good strategy for storing the tokens depends entirely on what you intend to do with the tokens.

Comment: I still think it needs more clarification about what you are going to use the tokens for after they are stored. For example, if quick access to a token is the most important thing, perhaps a hash table is best. If maintaining order is important, perhaps a hash table won't work. This is the type of information that would help me answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about "storing an allocation" at all. When you allocate memory, and write data into that memory, that is storing the data. There isn't really any other way to do it, except, like, on disk or something.

Answer (score 0):

Generally tokens are not stored to file.  They are requested by the parser when the parser is ready to read more input.

As such, tokens are stored in memory on the program's heap, and after they have been processed (which might be long before the file is fully parsed) they are freed.

--- Update to follow the edit ---

If you are worried about excessive allocation and deallocation, then you have a number of solutions, depending on the detail of the issue you are attempting to solve.

For strings, you can create them through a "string builder" interface, which checks to see if a string is already present with that text, and if so, returns a reference to the already present string.  Note that for this to work properly, all returned strings must be immutable (as changing a string in one reference will change the string in all references).  Similar solutions are possible for numbers, boolean values, etc.

For token reuse, you can make the token into a structure that mostly references by pointer the data likely to "used" by the parser.  That way the parser grabs the "fields" of the token, and the "skeleton" token can be added back to a "reuse queue".  The reuse queue should reset the "data" references of the token before returning it to the tokenizer, which would be rewritten to ask the queue for it's data structures.  In the event that there are no tokens "in the queue" the queue should silently allocate them.

Other solutions exist too, depending on how crafty you want to get.

Comment: I've updated the question to address some of the edit's issues.